# How to handle Textbox events in an OOP way?

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to define a class which represents a textbox and gives it some custom functionality to handle events like keyup.

I've defined the following Javascript class:

```
var AutoSaveTextBox = function(element) {
    this.textBox = $(element);
    this.init();
  }

AutoSaveTextBox.prototype.init = function() {
    this.textBox.onkeyup = function(e) {
      if(!e) e = window.event;
      this.textBox.handleKeyUp(e);
    }
  }

  AutoSaveTextBox.prototype.handleKeyUp = function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode
    var submitKeyCodes = [9, 13] //9:Tab, 13:Enter

    if(submitKeyCodes.indexOf(keyCode)>-1)
      console.log("You Pressed Submit");
  }
```

**How can I apply this class to every textbox on my page which has the class 'auto-save' so that every time one of these text boxes is typed in this class handles it?**

I've tried to apply it using the following, but it has been unsuccessful so far:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

  $('.auto-save').each(function(){
    new AutoSaveTextBox(this);
  });

});
```

Comment: You could use the [jQuery UI widget factory](https://jqueryui.com/widget/). Thats build to solve your problem (how to create stateful jquery plugins).

Comment: You should read up on how to create jQuery plugins. Your goal is to have something like this: `$('.auto-save').autoSaveTextBox();`, and have jQuery handle the rest.

Answer (score -1):

you can assing keyup event of textboxes with you object key up event,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

   $('.auto-save').each(function(){
     var x = new AutoSaveTextBox(this);
     $(this).keyup(x.handleKeyUp);
   });

  });
```